# Error upon customization publishing only when logged out

Tags: acumatica

Can someone explain why this error occurs every time I have to log back in after a customization is published?

If I delete the Acumatica instance and re-create it, linking to the existing database - it then works fine.  If it times out and I have to log in again, I get this error:

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

 Compiler Error Message: CS0117: 'PX.Data.PXLogin' does not contain a definition for 'EulaRequired'

 Source Error:


 Line 633:                                              username :
 Line 634:                                              string.Format("{0}@{1}", username, company);
 Line 635:      if (username == "admin" && PXLogin.EulaRequired(fullname))
 Line 636:      {
 Line 637:          PXContext.Session.SetString("EulaRequired", fullname);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what was causing this, but I've deleted the instance of Acumatica, removed all my class library references in the customization project and started over.  This seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your customization, are you including any of the PX*.dll libraries? If so you might be replacing the correct version needed for your site. Make sure the only dll file ins your customization are those that you created.

Comment: Yes - I always make sure my references are to the instance I'm working with.

Comment: The comment was to make sure your customisation project doesn't include any Acumatica site files. Your library would of course have a reference to site files as needed.